# GUVI TIMED L1 files and netCDF

Tags: netcdf, panoply

I am having an issue, which has essentially seemed to have split into two different issues. I was initially trying to work with TIMED satellite data, starting off with GUVI 1C data. Rummaging around http://www.timed.jhuapl.edu and other  sites, they made it clear the the data format was netCDF - which is unfamiliar to me. Regardless, it was downloaded, and I got the following (for Win 10 OS, 64-bit):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So initially speaking, where is the actual application to use netCDF?

Unsure, I downloaded Panolpy to help out.

Then I proceeded to download some TIMED GUVI L1 files:

And now I can't seem to open the L1C file - although according to the site it was supposed to be a netCDF file.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded a 1C file from the TIMED GUVI L1 page at 
http://guvitimed.jhuapl.edu/data_products

After uncompressing the gzipped download, I appended a .nc extension to the file and was able to open it in Panoply. The file information shown there indicated that the file is a netCDF-3 (classic netCDF) file.

Strictly speaking, adding the .nc extension isn't necessary, but if you don't do so, then in Panoply's open-file chooser, you have to click on the file format popup menu and select "All datasets" before Panoply will allow you to select the file in the directory listing.

The data in the 1C file I downloaded does not include sufficient metadata for Panoply to figure out the georeference grinding scheme, so it wasn't able to make any particular useful plots.